# Quantos apps é possível ter na Google Play

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

Se é possível, alguém sabe quantos apps são possíveis ter em uma mesma conta na Google Play ?

Comment: Não há limites. O único limite é a quantidade de uploads de APKs por dia (15).

Comment: Creio q não tem limite! voce pode ter quantos quiser!

Answer (score 2):

Não foi encontrado nada que fala sobre limitação de quantidade de APKs na conta de desenvolvedor do Google Play Publish, porém existe um limite que trata-se da quantidade diária que 15 APK. Veja a mensagem retornada para o desenvolvedor no momento em que vai fazer o *upload*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto ao tamanho de cada aplicação, o Google [anunciou (28 de setembro de 2015)](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html) um alteração para ajudar os desenvolvedores, alterando o tamanho do APK de `50MB` para `100MB`, podendo ser [expansível de acordo com a documentação](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html?utm_campaign=100MB-APKs-Play-928&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog). Veja também mais detalhe aqui [nessa documentação](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#apk).

Aproveitando a oportunidade, há uma lista no qual fala sobre o [limite de valor para cada aplicação de acordo com a região](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286) que é útil saber.